# Predicted probabilities for binary labels by Randon Forest and XGBoost

Tags: classification, random-forest, prediction, boosting

#### Task

Binary classification for an imbalanced dataset with 70 positive samples and 700 negative samples

#### Data

Oversample positive samples to match the number of negatives. Each sample has 10 features.

#### Model

By cross-validation, the tree-based methods gave better performance than Logistic regression and two-layered dense neural networks. The methods in use are the XGBoost api for Sklearn and the RandomForestClassifier in sklearn.

#### Training result

Normalized confusion matrix for testing data by XGBoost:
$$\quad\quad true\quad false$$
$$true\quad 0.71\quad 0.29$$
$$false\quad 0.33\quad 0.67$$

Normalized confusion matrix for testing data by Random Forest:
$$\quad\quad true\quad false$$
$$true\quad 0.77\quad 0.23$$
$$false\quad 0.27\quad 0.73$$

#### The hyperparameter settings

```py
PARAM_CONFIG = {
     'random_forest':{
         'n_estimators':80,
         'criterion':'entropy',
         'min_samples_leaf':20,
         'max_depth':3
     },
     'xgboost':{
         'max_depth':3,
         'learning_rate':0.0001,
         'objective':'binary:logistic',
         'scale_pos_weight': 1,
         'n_estimators': 50,
         'subsample': 0.8
     }
 }
```

#### Predicted probability on independent dataset

[image]

#### The question

Now comes to my problem, the model performances from training are very close for both methods. But when I looked into the predicted probabilities, XGBoost gives always marginal probabilities, which is not the case for random forest.

XGBoost and Random Forest gave the same prediction accuracy but XGBoost is less confident for all samples. What could go wrong here? or How should one explain this?

Comment: This clustering of the probabilities appears to be a known "feature" of gradient boosting: see https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/14527/xgboost-predict-probabilities?noredirect=1#comment18277_14527 for a different version of the same problem.  I wouldn't take the XGBoost outputs as real predicted probabilities, myself.

Comment: @jbowman Thanks a lot for the link. I will do more test to find out why the xgboost scores are slightly above 0.5. The probability calibration might alter the clustering a bit.

Comment: Did you tune the xgboost hyperparameters? That's a very low learning rate and n_estimators. I wonder if the xgboost model just hasn't been able to move far away from predicting a 0.5 with such a small learning rate.